# Вопрос по бд mysql

Tags: mysql

В БД mysql есть одна единственная таблица «abc» с полями: id (int), name (varchar), cnt (int). В таблице
содержится порядка 10 млн записей. Что нужно сделать, что быстро работали следующие запросы (3 разных
случая)? Все остальные факторы кроме скорости чтения не критичны.

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE name = 'xxx' AND cnt = yyy
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE cnt = xxx AND name LIKE 'yyy%'
SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY cnt ASC
```

Comment: Индексы по полям `name` `cnt` имеются? Запрос с `name LIKE 'yyy%'` будет выполнятся медленно. Вряд ли его можно как-то существенно ускорить

Comment: Можно добавить/настроить полнотекстовый поиск вместо like.

Comment: [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) - может, кому-нибудь пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать индексы на столбцах, по которым будут производиться поисковые операции. В данном случае, для первого и второго запроса это столбцы name и cnt. Для третьего запроса – столбец cnt.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name_cnt ON abc (name, cnt);
CREATE INDEX idx_cnt ON abc (cnt);
```