# Mysql вопрос по быстрым запросам

Tags: mysql

В таблице много записей, мне нужно чтобы быстро работали следующие запросы

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE name = 'xxx' AND cnt = yyy
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE cnt = xxx AND name LIKE 'yyy%'
SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY cnt ASC
```

Для первого
Использую

```
Alter table abc add index abc_index_name(name, cnt);
```

Но подходит только для первого запроса

Мне нужно чтобы быстро работали эти два

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE cnt = xxx AND name LIKE 'yyy%'
SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY cnt ASC
```

Comment: Удалите созданный индекс и выполните `ALTER TABLE abc ADD INDEX abc_index_name(cnt, name);` - такой ускорит все  три запроса.

Comment: Так я такой и выполняю, написал же, он только для первого

Comment: Что значит "такой"? сравни - причём по отдельным буквам.

Comment: Cnt и name ты местами поменял.

Comment: Правильно. Порядок полей в выражении индекса - это **критически** важно.

Comment: Просто сейчас нет возможности проверить. Оно должно и для 3 подходить?

Comment: Конечно. Ведь условий отбора нет, а выражение сортировки является префиксом выражения индекса. *сейчас нет возможности проверить.* С чего бы? online fiddle вроде никуда не делись...

Comment: В таблице просто более 10 млн запросов

Comment: В таблице просто очень очень много записей и я  хотел ускорить работу запросов, которые я привёл

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопрос по бд mysql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1262486/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b4-mysql)